# made image-click-counter which is buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run the below code, for every click it displays count again and again. How can I optimize it?

```
var i = 1;
var txt1;

$("#target").click(function(e) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
    txt1 = $("<p></p>").text("count=" + i);
    $("body").append(txt1);
});
```

Comment: Rather then append try to use html. And not to use with body use it with any div. Such as <div class="counter"></div> and in js $(".counter").html(txt1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fixed `p` tag within the body and update its text content on each click.

```js
var i = 0;
$("#target").click(function(e) {
  $("#p").text("count = " + ++i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="target" alt="Click" src="">
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: the id target should be for the image right?? because when we click on the image, the the counter should start. then why button??

Comment: @SaiCharan :  it can be any HTML element

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend @Pranav's approach. However you can also get the desired result by creating `p` object outside the click handler. In the event handler set the `.text()` and then `.append()`.

```js
var i = 0;
var txt1 = $("<p></p>");
$("#target").click(function(e) {
  $("body").append(txt1.text("count=" + ++i));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='target' src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/742006974644e0e1d9a5a3bbde15947e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
```

Comment: can i know why the id target can't be given to the img tag?

Comment: @SaiCharan, Yes you can see the updated snippet. You can set id to any element. Is image creating using some plugin or dynamically? Can you share the html